# PyOpenGL. x = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX) Returns Memory Address

Tags: python, pygame, pyopengl

I'm trying to store the location of a cube in the value `x` and when I try and `print(x)` instead of printing the location, it prints

```
<OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x043E63A0>
```

Extra Info:

```
Windows 8.1 64-Bit
Python 3.4.3 32-Bit
PyOpenGL 3.1.1 32-Bit
PyGame 32-Bit (Can't find the version)
```

I have admin perms on my PC and the install of PyOpenGL and PyGame seemed to go ok. Thanks. If there's anythin else you would like to see e.g. the full code for my script, just ask.

**EDIT**:
This question is no longer needing an answer as I've moved on from this. Thanks to all who tried to help out, you're all amazing people for giving your time to do so.

Comment: @Rafael Cardoso do you have an answer?

Comment: could you explain better? The title and the description are not very clear

Comment: Basically, I have drawn a cube in PyOpenGL and want to store the location of that cube in the variable 'x'. However, when I print 'x', instead of getting co-ordinates [0,2,3,4,5] or something like that, I get <OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x0(numbers)>. Thanks for actually responding with constructive criticism. All the other answers I have got are either insulting or people just ignore me.

Comment: By the way, I changed the title too

Answer (score 1):

I really love people who provide answers that aren't noob-friendly.

Rafael Cardoso seems to expect you know how to use VBOs and such.
(from your wording, I can assume you hardly know much about what you're doing)

I'm not too skilled with ctypes or OpenGL.arrays,
(I just got into them last night trying to remove numpy from a GLSL 3D viewer)
but from my python experience, what he's saying is you need to do something like:

```
from OpenGL import GL, arrays
x = GL.glGetDoublev(GL.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
handler = arrays.ctypesarrays.CtypesArrayHandler()
print handler.asArray(x,typecode=None)
```

I can't really help because I have cruddy numpy installed which PyOpenGL recognizes...
So for me, glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX) returns a disgusting `numpy.array()` object rather than an `OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays.c_double_Array_4_Array_4` object...

my tests with the above prints this:

```
>>> h = arrays.ctypesarrays.CtypesArrayHandler()
>>> x = GL.glGetDoublev(GL.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
>>> x
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> h.asArray( x, ctypes.c_double )
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

From the way it looks, it's not very useful.

EDIT:
forgot about my VM, which has a python installation without numpy :)

same result though:

```
>>> from OpenGL import GL, arrays
>>> h = arrays.ctypesarrays.CtypesArrayHandler()
>>> x = GL.glGetDoublev(GL.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
>>> x
<OpenGL.arrays.lists.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x015FEE90>
>>> h.asArray( x )
<OpenGL.arrays.lists.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x015FEE90>
```

EDIT2:
this works:

```
>>> [[ c for c in r] for r in x]
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

you really don't even need to reformat as `<OpenGL.arrays.lists.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x015FEE90>` is a 2D iterator. ;)

```
>>> for r in x: print r

<OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605CB0>
<OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605D50>
<OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605CB0>
<OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605D50>
```

another example:

```
>>> list(x)
[<OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605CB0>, <OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605D00>, <OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605DA0>, <OpenGL.constants.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x01605DF0>]
```