# pyOpenGL array location print

Tags: python-2.7

I'm getting stuff like this instead of what I want to see. Did I not install GL? I installed it with pip on windows 8 as pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate which should have given me all that I need I thought.

```
<OpenGL.arrays.ctypesarrays.c_double_Array_4_Array_4 object at 0x043E00D0>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29681457/2588654)? Can you provide what code you using to generate this object instead of the array?

Comment: I commented on there with the same question again. sorry for the empty feedback.